# deleting letters from strings without string methods or imports?

Tags: python

This is a homework question. I need to define a function that takes a word and letter and deletes all occurrences of that letter in the word. I can't use stuff like regex or the string library. I've tried...

```
def delete(word,letter):
    word = []
    char = ""
    if char != letter: 
        word+=char
    return word
```

and

```
def delete(word,letter):
    word = []
    char = ""
    if char != letter:  #I also tried "if char not letter" for both
        word = word.append(char)
    return word
```

Both don't give any output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, look at your functions closely:

```
def delete(word,letter):
    word = []
    char = ""
    if char != letter: 
        word+=char # or `word = word.append(char)` in 2nd version
    return word
```

So, the function gets a word and a letter passed in. The first thing you do is throw away the word, because you are overwriting the local variable with a different value (a new empty list). Next, you are initializing an empty string `char` and compare its content (it’s empty) with the passed letter. If they are not equal, i.e. if `letter` is not an empty string, the empty string in `char` is added to the (empty list) `word`. And then `word` is returned.

Also note that you cannot add a string to a list. The `+` operation on lists is only implemented to combine two lists, so your `append` version is definitelly less wrong. Given that you want a string as a result, it makes more sense to just store the result as one to begin with.

Instead of adding an empty string to an empty string/list when something completely unrelated to the passed word happens, what you rather want to do is keep the original word intact and somehow look at each character. You basically want to loop through the word and keep all characters that are not the passed letter; something like this:

```
def delete(word, letter):
    newWord = '' # let's not overwrite the passed word
    for char in word:
        # `char` is now each character of the original word.
        # Here you now need to decide if you want to keep the
        # character for `newWord` or not.
    return newWord
```

The `for var in something` will basically take the sequence `something` and execute the loop body for each value of that sequence, identified using the variable `var`. Strings are sequences of characters, so the loop variable will contain a single character and the loop body is executed for each character within the string.

Comment: Thank You so much! I finally got it.

Comment: beautiful explanation! Beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with `word` passed to your function.  Ultimately, you need to iterate over the word passed into your function (`for character in word: doSomething_with_character`) and build your output from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete(word, ch):
    return filter(lambda c: c != ch, word)
```

Basically, just a linear pass over the string, dropping out letters that match `ch`.

`filter` takes a higher order function and an `iterable`. A string is an `iterable` and iterating over it iterates over the characters it contains. `filter` removes the elements from the iterable for which the higher order function returns `False`.

In this case, we `filter` out all characters that are equal to the passed `ch` argument.

Comment: I'm sure the teacher won't be suspicious at all when a Python 101 student two months into the semester suddenly whips out `filter` and a lambda function...

Comment: @MattDMo It's a built-in. A quick stroll through the docs and reading the first chapter of the official tutorial gets you through `map`, `reduce`, `filter` and the rest of the very basic functional programming stuff. Plus, if it's **Python** 101, not kindergarden intro to programming, then some functional is a must, most of the standard lib uses higher order functions extensively.

Answer (score 0):

I like the functional style @TC1 and @user2041448 that is worth understanding.  Here's another implementation:

```
def delete( letter, string ):
    s2 = []
    for c in string:
        if c!=letter:
             s2.append( c )

     return ''.join(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first function uses + operator with a list which probably isn't the most appropriate choice. The + operator should probably be reserved for strings (and use .append() function with lists).

If the intent is to return a *string*, **assign ""** instead of [], and **use + operators**.

If the intent is to return a *list of characters* **assign []**, and **use .append() function**.

*Change the name of the variable* you are using to construct the returned value.

Assigning anything to word gets rid of the content that was given to the function as an argument.

so make it **result=[] OR result=""** etc..

ALSO:

the way you seem to be attempting to solve this requires you to loop over the characters in the original string, the code you posted does not loop at all.

you could use a for loop with this type of semantic:

```
for characterVar in stringVar:
    controlled-code-here
code-after-loop
```

you can/should change the names of course, but i named them in a way that should help you understand. In your case stringVar would be replaced with word and you would append or add characterVar to result if it isn't the deleted character. Any code that you wish to be contained in the loop must be indented. the first unindented line following the control line indicates to python that the code comes AFTER the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
def delete(word, letter):
    new_word = ""
    for i in word:
        if i != letter:
            new_word += i
    return new_word
```